# How to set fail2ban with apf?

Tags: firewall, iptables, fail2ban

I just installed fail2ban and the apf firewall. Those 2 seems to be not working together. Fail2ban have added some iptable rules but they are not working.

When I issue `/etc/init.d/iptables status` it says:

```
bash: /etc/init.d/iptables: No such file or directory...
```

How can I make it work with apf? I have Ubuntu 11.04 in a VPS!

Comment: `sudo iptables -vnL` instead of your status command.

Comment: @jippie That command works but fail2ban is not!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `fail2ban` is configured to work with iptables; this generates a configuration conflict with APF because `fail2ban` adds a chain to iptables and when you reload APF it wipes that fail2ban chain each time.

Fortunately you can configure fail2ban to have many different actions, this allows it to be able to work with iptables, shorewall, etc.

To make APF and fail2ban work together we just need to add an apf action to `fail2ban`:
I created the `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/apf.conf` based on the `shorewall.conf` and we just need to edit `actionban` and `actionunban` to this:

```
actionban = apf --deny <ip>
actionunban = apf --remove <ip>
```

Then we have to configure fail2ban to use apf by editing the `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` file.

The line we are looking for is:

```
banaction = apf
```